# Gitlab stage runs despite rules condition forbids

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have problem with my gitlab pipeline - stage `my_stage` runs even if I commit files to `src/main/java` folder. What I want to achieve is to run in only on Merge Request **AND** only if changes were done to src/test/resources.

```
stages:
  - my_stage 

my_stage_mr:
  stage: my_stage 
  image: myimage-11-slim
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      changes:
        - src/test/resources/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
stages:
  - my_stage 

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

my_stage_mr:
  stage: my_stage 
  script:
    - echo "running only when changes are in resources folder and on merge request"
  rules:
    - changes:
      - src/test/resources/*
```